# From the 4th to the 8th of June - [date ranges]

Tags: grammar, dates

In a business letter, 
what's the correct or more frequent way to write date ranges?

> from the 4th to the 8th of June 2014, we have been working on the
>   project

or

> from 4 to 8 June 2014, we have been working on the project

or

> In June 2014, 4 to 8, we have been working on the project

Comment: I'd say first because the other two sound kind of odd, not wrong but not very frequently used. Either way its an ambiguous question so personal preference matters the most.

Comment: why ambiguous? how can I improve it?

Comment: Because there is no hard and fast rule regarding which one to use specifically, as in some people may prefer the 2nd one for formal use or some may use something else altogether.

Comment: Jess Stone, it's worth remembering that what is the correct way to write date ranges, depends on which English you use. As you can see in the answer from **Gary's Student**, American English involves writing dates as month, day and then year, as well as use of the word *through*. This is not the case in the UK.

Comment: I am writing in 'international' English, neither American nor British. I am just addressing to a foreign person, whose native language is not English(American/British)

Comment: Jess Stone, there isn't one, single, 'international' English. There are different accents, dialects and other uses of the language, around the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Tristanr I would have taken "through" to be explicitly inclusive, unlike "to" which would leave me wondering if the work stopped on the 7th. I would have assumed "through" was ok in the UK - I certainly wouldn't bat an eyelid hearing it in Ireland, which of course is not conclusive. On the "foreign person" thing, agreed that there's no international standard, but since we're explicitly talking non-US, I'd go with day, month, year since that's by far the most popular outside the US https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: CupawnTae, yes. That date format is also common in the UK. I haven't heard anyone use "through", like that, in the UK. I've only heard Americans use it and it seems particularly bizarre because it is so very different from normal wordings in this part of the world. I remember when I first heard it, I had to research it on the internet to find out what exactly, it meant.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are acceptable.  The use of *8th* is more common than either *8 June* or *the eighth of June.*

Because both dates are in the past, consider using past tense.

"We worked on the project from June 4th 2004 through June 8th 2014."

The use of *through* is slightly less ambiguous.

Comment: should the [Present Perfect Continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html) be used ?

Comment: @JessStone Given the two dates in your example, I would use simple past tense.

Comment: being it a period of time, i think it can relate to this: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=694283

Answer (score 1):

> From June 4th through 8th of 2014...

or

> From the 4th through 8th of June in 2014...

or

> From June 4 through June 8, 2014

The first option you posted is normal, but the other two are nonstandard.

Comment: I think that using "through" with dates like this is particular to AmEng.

Answer (score -1):

Employing en dash may help, 4—6 June

Comment: Have you seen this type of use in a formal business letter?

Comment: I'd certainly be unafraid to use it, but I don't see how it's any different from using "to" instead of the dash. Anand, could you [edit] your answer to explain **how** the en-dash might help?

Comment: The symbol you have in your answer is actually an **em** dash. An en dash is only the length of an N: `–`